# Debugging an XP bar (another issue)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I worked on my code a bit more, but now it doesn't seem that it works with a parseInt when I call widthGenerator or even increments in the for loop inside frame which is in move. Here is my code:

```
<body class="w3-container">
<div class="w3-progress-container w3-round-xlarge">
    <div id="myBar" class="w3-progressbar w3-round-xlarge" style="width:1%"></div>
</div>

<button class="w3-btn" onclick="move()">Click Me</button> 

<script>

function widthGenerator() {
var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
var parseQuestion = parseInt(question, 10);
  if (isNaN(Number(question))) {
      var width = (question * 2.33463);
  } else {
    question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
  };

return width;
}
function move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
var id = setInterval(frame, 1);
var startWidth = 0;
var generateWidth = widthGenerator()
function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        for (var x = startWidth; x < generateWidth; x++) {
            elem.style.width = x + '%';
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to clearly separate out the JavaScript and HTML into separate code blocks, as well as fixing the indention you've included here.  Also you should reword your question, as `now it doesn't seem that it accepts my parseInt when widthGenerator is called, or even increments in the for loop.` doesn't make a _ton_ of sense for someone unfamiliar with your project.

Comment: The variable "width" in the frame-function doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Where did you declare `width` _outside_ `widthGenerator`? Did you mean to use `generateWidth`? Look into your console for errors. Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to notice mistakes like these.

Comment: I have widthGenerator create a variable named width, then it returns width.

Comment: OK! Found the issue. Turns out I forgot to set the condition of the if statement of widthGenerator `isNaN(Number(question))` equal to false. It returns width but won't increment.